# Best practice for Connection String Object

Tags: c#, object, ado.net, database-connection

I have two `methods` in my application for calling two different `SPs`.

```
public List<Products> GetProducts(string productName, string productCode)
{
   SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CatalogueConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_Products", sqlconn);
   .....
}
```

And I have another method too in the same class which creates the `SqlConnection` Object again. So my question is what should be the best practice for creating `connection` object so I don't have to `Create` it again and again in every method. Is it a good practice to create connection object for every method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just have a global static variable similar to this:

```
public static class MyCachedSettings
{
     public static string ConnectionString = 
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CatalogueConnectionString" ].ConnectionString;

     public static SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
}
```

and then use it:

```
public List<Products> GetProducts(string productName, string productCode)
{
   SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(MyCachedSettings.ConnectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_Products", sqlconn);
   .....
}
```

Comment: Do I have to create the `SqlConnection` object every time? Like If I have 5 different methods I have to create this object 5 times?

Comment: No you don't. You can create one connection and re-use it.... Just make sure that you don't re-use it across threads. I'll modify the example above

Answer (score 0):

You should create some class or method to handle how to execue command to db. In this case I use static for allow everyone to use it without recreate the new instance. And ParamsInfo is DTO class that store name and the value of the param object.

Ex.

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string connectionString, string storedProcedure, params ParamsInfo[] params)
{ ... }
```

And let it handle everything for you.

[See How to use DataSet](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset)

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Products> GetProducts(SqlConnection sqlconn, string productName, string productCode)
{

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_Products", sqlconn);

}
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection("");
sqlconn.Open();
GetProducts(sqlconn, "productName", "code");
GetProducts1(sqlconn, "productName", "code");
sqlconn.Close();
```